# XSD for Dataset

Tags: xml, api, xsd, schema

I want to write a xsd for a dataset with a dynamic name and dynamic elements.

xml will look like this:

```
<dataset>
   <dymanicTableName>
      <dynamicColumnName>rowValule</dynamicColumnName>
   </dynamicTableName>
</dataset>
```

I have tried to use  like below

```
<xs:element name ="DataSet">
     <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
       </xs:sequence>
       <xs:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
```

but this won't allow for a dynamic table name. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in the above example:

1. You have a typo in `dynamicTableName`. Fix it, then it'd look like:

   ```
   <dataset>
      <dynamicTableName>
         <dynamicColumnName>rowValule</dynamicColumnName>
      </dynamicTableName>
   </dataset>
   ```
2. Your element's name is `dataset` and not `DataSet`. So change your XSD to:

   ```
   <xs:element name ="dataset">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
     </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   ```

Now your code should validate.